# Validation on a vuetify v-text-field in a v-form using rules

Tags: typescript, vue.js, validation, vuetify.js

I'm new to vue and I'm trying to get validation to work on a v-text-field.  I have three fields, 2 editable and one not, the one that is not is calculated from the other two but only when they are valid.  so i have three fields defined thus (have simplified everything to A,B and C to make it clear):

```
<v-form ref="stif-form">
      <v-row class="ma-4 mt-10 material-input">
        <v-text-field ref="a" sm v-model="A" label="A" dense suffix="kPa" :rules="[...floatRules,positiveRule]" />
      </v-row>
      <v-row class="ma-4 mt-10 material-input">
        <v-text-field ref="b" sm v-model="B" dense :rules="[...floatRules, positiveRule]"/>
      </v-row>
      <v-row class="ma-4 mt-10 material-input">
        <v-text-field sm v-model="C" label="C" disabled dense  />
      </v-row>
   </v-form>
```

Then I have 3 properties, A, B, C, two watches (using typescript so this is with decorators but these are equivalent to js watches)

```
 @Watch('A')
  onAChanged (a: number) {
    this.setC(a, this.B)
  }

@Watch('B')
   onBChanged (b: number) {
     this.setC(this.A, b)
   }
```

and in setC i want to then find out if A and B are valid by just finding those fields and seeing if they are valid (rather than having to write duplicate code to do the validation).  I have tried this:

```
setC (a : number, b: number) {
    if (!(this.$refs['a'] as HTMLFormElement).hasError && 
        !(this.$refs['b'] as HTMLFormElement).hasError){
      this.C= (a+b).toFixed(2)
    }
    else this.C= ''
  }
```

The hasError lines work and return true and false as you'd expect except that he hasError state is for the previous key press which means if you type an invalid char, you have to type another one before it sets C to blank.  I feel like I'm missing something here.  What is the correct approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a habit of answering my own questions :)

The validation is performed by the form so by doing the following I get the most recent validation:

```
setC (a : number, b: number) {
    if ((this.$refs['stif-form'] as HTMLFormElement).validate()){
      ...
    }
    else this.C= ''
  }
```